What is that notation called and how to read it? $\mathcal{L} = G (\bar e ν) (\bar u d)$
I'm reading "Zee A. - Quantum Field Theory, as Simply as Possible (2023)".
CHAPTER V.３The weak and the electroweak interactions

For ease of presentation, I will now write this as it is written in the
quark era: $\mathcal{L} = G (\bar e ν) (\bar u d)$


Now that you have almost mastered quantum field theory, you are initiated (recall chapter IV.2) into reading this secret hand-writing:

I've tried to re-read IV.2 but could not find this notation, also searched the book by ") (", "L =", "= G".

from right to left in $\mathcal{L}$, $d$ annihilates a down quark, $\bar u$ creates an up
quark, $ν$ creates an antineutrino, and $\bar e$ creates an electron, thus describing
the process $d → u + e^- + \bar ν$. The Fermi constant $G$ measures the probability
amplitude for the process to occur. (I have simplified by suppressing various “inessential” factors in $\mathcal{L}$.

It is about Beta_decay but I could not find such notation on the wikipedia page. Nor via websearch for "L = G (e ν) (u d)".
How to read such notation? E.g. what parenthesis mean, how symbols for  creation differ from ones for annihilation.

The parentheses are irrelevant; they’re just there for clarity that the antispinor and spinor inside form a scalar. Have you learned what a Dirac spinor is?

how creation differs from annihilation What are you asking? Obviously creating and destroying particles are different operations.

@Ghoster. Spinors were briefly mentioned in the book "Dirac
was forced to set ψ equal to a 4-component mathematical object known as a
spinor", can't say I understand them well.

@Ghoster, in the notation I see no difference which symbol corresponds to which. "
how creation differs from annihilation "

The $e$, $\nu$, $u$, and $d$ are spinor fields describing electrons, neutrinos, up quarks, and down quarks. The bar indicates an operation called a Dirac adjoint.

How the bars or lack of bars relate to creation or annihilation is beyond the scope of a comment. This interaction Lagrangian actually describes multiple different processes, not just the one mentioned. Hopefully you’ll get a full answer.

The pairs inside the parens are called “covariant Dirac bilinears” if you want a search term. Zee’s notation is suppressing both the spinor indices and a Dirac gamma matrix between the antispinor and spinor, necessary to form a “weak current”. The Lagrangian is the interaction of one weak current with another weak current.

@Ghoster 's garland of comments has essentially answered most of your question. Presumably, Tony has already explained that, when the Dirac spinor  destroys a particle (and creates its antiparticle), the conjugate one creates its particle and destroys its antiparticle.
The constant $G_F$ in front is the Fermi constant which quantifies how copiously, or rarely, beta decay occurs, the strength/weakness of the weak interaction involved; and summarizes the effects, at low energy, of the virtual W boson exchanged.
Tony, emulating Fermi almost a hundred years ago, has wisely omitted Dirac matrices which would only confuse you with their technical spin and chirality information. The actual SM semileptonic effective hamiltonian involved in the decay amplitude looks like
$$
\propto G_F ~~ \overline{ \psi_e}\gamma^\mu \frac{1-\gamma^5}{2} \psi_ν ~~\overline{\psi_u}\gamma_\mu \frac{1-\gamma^5}{2} \psi_ d ,
$$
and it does schematically what you quote. It is called the (weak) current-current effective hamiltonian.
In Fermi's time, they didn't know about quarks, so Fermi's actual guess destroyed a neutron and created a proton, instead. Destroying and creating particles to describe decays was revolutionary at the time, and uncommon for field theory.
You might, or might not, find this answer informative.
